# Matlab: find first smaller or larger element in an array

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays of different size A and B. I am comparing A to B and want to find for each element in A the first element in B that is smaller/larger.

I would like to use something like ismember(A,B), except that I am not looking for identical elements. The problem is that 'find' will not work because A and B are not the same size.

I now used a loop but am looking for a more elegant way to program this. Here is the loop:

```
        for zz=1:length(A)
            tmpmax(zz) = find(B>=A(zz),1);
            tmpmin(zz) = find(B<=A(zz),1,'last');                
        end
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Immo

Comment: Even if they were the same size, find would still be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the loop with:

```
tmpmin = arrayfun(@(x) find(B>=x,1), A);
tmpmax = arrayfun(@(x) find(B<=x,1,'last'), A );
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how often you will do this, and how large your vectors are. But I would suggest preprocessing the array `B`. For example, consider the test case:

```
B = rand(1,10)
B =
  0.82346 0.69483 0.3171 0.95022 0.034446 0.43874 0.38156 0.76552 0.7952 0.18687
```

We will need to build a cumulative min and max vector. If `B` is fairly long, there are several ways this might be done.

```
Bmin = B;
N = inf;
while numel(Bmin) < N
  N = numel(Bmin);
  k = find(diff(Bmin) >= 0);
  Bmin(k+1) = [];
end
Bmax = B;
N = inf;
while numel(Bmax) < N
  N = numel(Bmax);
  k = find(diff(Bmax) <= 0);
  Bmax(k+1) = [];
end
```

then

```
Bmin
Bmin =
   0.82346      0.69483       0.3171     0.034446

Bmax
Bmax =
   0.82346      0.95022
```

(I could have built `Bmin` and `Bmax` using a simple for loop too, and it would probably have been faster, but the while loop was more fun to write.)

Now it is simple. In order to find the first element of `B` that is larger than any given value, use `histc` on `Bmax`. And since `histc` is vectorized, the operation is fast. To do it, look at the second return argument of `histc`. Or, you could write a vectorized binary search scheme. `histc` will also solve the minimum element problem, by flipping the order of the elements in `Bmin`.

If your goal is to find the INDEX of the element, this too is simple enough, by retaining that information when you build `Bmin` and `Bmax`.